# Amazon SP API Orders API getting old orders with null information

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api, amazonsellercentral

Using SP-API Orders API v0

I'm getting orders using LastUpdatedAfter to fetch orders with a status of Shipped.  This works fine, but approximately 1% of the orders are very old, as in shipped weeks, months or even years ago, with no indication of why the order has been updated.  I can find no correlation in any of the values that would explain why these orders were updated, but one thing is common: the ShippingAddress fields are usually null and the BuyerInfo BuyerEmail is always null.

This is a problem because we import these orders into the client's ERP system for processing.  We have a method to check for existing Amazon Order IDs and we can update existing orders, but most of the time the orders have been long closed, and the updates generally only remove shipping and email information, as far as we can tell.  My inclination is to simply ignore these necro'd orders, but without knowing why they are being updated, that doesn't feel safe.

Why would Amazon be updating weeks or even years old orders and removing the shipping an email information, and it is safe to ignore these updates?